# How to avoid changing event when a item was selected in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm create selection to select data from DB but set **ID="myselect"** for selector

But this ajax will call if I have selected an items and change to another items i want to call ajax only one times when user click on its items.

```
$(document).on("click", "#myselect", function (e) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/teller/assignTo',
        dataType: 'json',
        Method: 'get',
        success: function (data, status) {

            var userId = data.users;
            $.each(userId, function (key, value) {
                $('#myselect').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(value.name));
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            throw new Error("Could not load  " + data);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<select name="assign_user_id" id="myselect" class="form-control" ></select>
```

Comment: you can use $(document).one instead $(document).on.. will be executed only once

Comment: $(document).on("change", "#myselect", function (e) {    // use change event instead of click

Comment: It can't work because the first time I have nay value in selection.

Comment: @anshu,
if you used one and if the first load fail it can't select after

Answer (score 1):

Try this

HTML

```
<select name="assign_user_id" id="myselect" class="form-control not-clicked" ></select>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).on("click", "#myselect", function (e) {
    if( $(this).hasClass( "not-clicked" ) ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/teller/assignTo',
            dataType: 'json',
            Method: 'get',
            success: function (data, status) {    
                var userId = data.users;
                $.each(userId, function (key, value) {
                    $('#myselect').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(value.name));
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                throw new Error("Could not load  " + data);
            }
        });
        $(this).removeClass("not-clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh I have append this select from another jquery so I have to used $(document).on(); if I used $(selector).on() it will not work

Comment: If that ajax loading fail I have to insert checked class again right? and it is good for performance or not

Comment: Just move '$(this).removeClass("not-clicked");' inside success fucntion.

Comment: It can't remove that class when I change removed class inside ajax